# Dictionary: Commonly Used English Acronyms and abbreviations at TeX.SX

Tags: discussion, acronyms

Many times in chat or at the main site we discuss with each other using acronyms (short forms/jargon) of single-liners.

In order to help new users, internet chat slang unaware users (myself), [non-native English speakers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=7681101#7681101) and many more I would like to collect here for keeping record [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7682049#7682049).

I think [Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) has already [trained the chat bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7682104#7682104) for this.

Comment: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) should give most of the abbreviations. Actually the origin is usually IRC and usenet jargon: [Internet slang (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_slang).

Comment: @Speravir I found there was no comprehensive meta Q&A on this and hence posted it. Thanks for the Internet slang link.

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/what-does-op-stand-for

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks i missed it. may be we should combine both with your link. I want to make a question which is searchable with `acronym`,`dictionary` which covers a wider base than just `OP`.